# How to save quote items in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

How to save quote items in Magento 2? I have quote id. I'm able to store quote table data but I want to store products name, sku which is going in `quote_item` table.

I am able to set Data in quote table . `$quote->setItemsqty($this->qty)`;

But i want to set Sku ,Name etc on `quote_item` table

Below is my Function on that function i am able to create quote

```
public function save(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote)
{


    if ($quote->getId()) {

       $currentQuote = $this->get($quote->getId(), [$quote->getStoreId()]);


     foreach ($currentQuote->getData() as $key => $value) {

          if (!$quote->hasData($key)) {
                $quote->setData($key, $value);
            }
        }


    $quote->setItemscount(count($this->sku)); 
    $quote->setItemsqty($this->qty);


    }


    $this->getSaveHandler()->save($quote);

    $quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
    $quoteItem->setProduct($product);

    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
    $quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();


    $this->customlog->info($quoteItem->getData());

    unset($this->quotesById[$quote->getId()]);
    unset($this->quotesByCustomerId[$quote->getCustomerId()]);
}
```

How to do it? Any idea?

Comment: Your question makes me confused. `quote_item` table has already name, sku.

Comment: yes its already have but i have quote id i want to save quote item data

Comment: Ah! You have a quote id, now, you want to load quote object add more quote items to this object?

Comment: yes i have quote id now i want to add items

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187828/magento-1-or-2-set-custom-product-weight-in-quote/355403#355403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setProduct` method of quote item object.

Inject <del>`\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory`</del> - `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory` in your constructor.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $cartItemFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $product;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory $cartItemFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product,
    ....
) {
    $this->cartItemFactory = $cartItemFactory;
    $this->product = $product;

}
```

In your method:

```
$product = $this->product->get($productSku);
$quoteItem = $this->cartItemFactory->create();
$quoteItem->setProduct($product);
$quote->addItem($quoteItem);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

**EDIT:**

I used `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory` instead of using `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory`

Comment: getting error ItemFactory does not exist' in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\magento2sapient5\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php:195

Comment: its not creating quote item row

Comment: {
  "message": "Cannot create quote"
}

Comment: i updated my functions

Comment: Still getting the same error quote_item table is not creating row with my quote id then how come data will save i corrected whatever changes you send me but still no luck can you correct me what is going wrong

Comment: Actually, I don't fully understand your code lines. How you create the quote object? You pretty sure that your code lines will create an quote object?

Comment: yes i corrected code now its working fine now thanks :)

Comment: but there is one more issue only sku is storing on quote_item table rest other field is not showing why ?

Comment: If you want to add more products, you should try with a foreach loop. However, need to put `$this->quoteItemFactory->create();` inside the loop.

Comment: no i mean price,qty,& many more data is not storing in that row only sku,name,storeid,products id is capturing please see the below screen http://screencast.com/t/SeQydFToH

Comment: Add `addQty($qty)` to quote item => ` $quoteItem->addQty(3);`

Comment: we have to do this for all other attribute ?i checked default magento api if we provide quote id few parameters {
 "cartItem": 
  {
    "item_id": 23,
    "sku": "Nokia Lumia",
    "qty": 20,
    "name": "Nokia Lumia",
    "price": 10,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "27"
  }

}  then it will store qty,price etc how they are doing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46336/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-magento12345).

Comment: i am on chat please respond

Comment: any luck have to got

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187828/magento-1-or-2-set-custom-product-weight-in-quote/355403#355403