# Magento 2 : Updating quote item

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, quoteitem, magento-2.1.4

I am trying to update quote item in magento2. But every time i am saving the item its creating a new item with the same quote id rather than updating it. Here is my code

```
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepo
        ){
            $this->_quoteRepo = $quoteRepo;
        }

public function updateItem(){
    $quote = $this->_quoteRepo->get('id here');
    foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $itemq){
    $itemq->setQty(5);
    $itemq->setPrice(20);
    $itemq->save();
    }
 }
```

But every time its saving an item.. a new item is getting generated. Dont know why. Also `I couldn't find any class which explicitly load qoute item in magento2`. Help will be appreciated.

In this question [`https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139298/how-to-save-quote-items-in-magento-2`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139298/how-to-save-quote-items-in-magento-2) they are setting the whole product... not trying to update it. When you set a product a new quote item will surely generate. But why its doing the same in case of updation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save quote items in magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139298/how-to-save-quote-items-in-magento-2)

Comment: Not same. I have edited my question.  @AnkitShah please check.

Comment: For the Magento 2.2+ refer this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182152/4492

Comment: How to update multiple quote Items qty programmatically in rest API any idea ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure about my below solution:

- *May be you need to load* **Quote item object by item id**
- *As you want set price* then using **setPrice()** you *cannot set your desire price for  that cart item*

> ```
> $item = $quote->getItemById($item->getId());
> if (!$item) {
>   continue;
> }
> $item->setQty((double) $qty);
> $item->setCustomPrice($price);
> $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
> $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
> $item->save();
> ```

Comment: how to update additional options

Comment: hi @Amit, How to update taxAmount for the item?, can we set custom tax amount for individual quote item?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are asking about is already done in `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost`
which is executed when we update cart on cart page of magento.
It runs `updateItems()` function of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` to update items in `quote_item` table . It take parameter in the form of array `$data ['item id of product']['attribute you want to update']`.

So , you can call  `updateItems()` on cart model object and pass the data accordingly to update items.Also if you are not getting item id you can get it like `$this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()` and then call `getItemId()` on each item.