# Programmatically update and persist bundle option quantity

Tags: quote, magento-2.2.1, bundle

I want to programmatically update the quantity of a bundle option of a item in the users cart.

Currently in the cart, a bundle with the option "12 x DIN A4 page".

This is what I have done so far

```
class ItemInfo [...]

/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
protected $quoteItem;

public function updateNumberOfPages($pages)
{
    $qtyOptions = $this->quoteItem->getQtyOptions();
    assert(count($qtyOptions) == 1);
    $option = reset($qtyOptions);

    $qty = $pages * $this->getNumberOfCopies();
    $this->quoteItem->updateQtyOption($option, $qty);
    $this->quoteItem->save($this);

    $this->quoteItem->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(true)->collectTotals();

    return $this;
}
```

So I call this function `updateNumberOfPages(4);`

A bit later in the same request, I want to fetch and the new totals:

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface */
protected $cartTotalsRepository;

...

$totals = $this->cartTotalsRepository->get($quoteItem->getQuoteId());
```

But here, the just updated item still reports "12 x DIN A4 page" - even I have set the qty above to 4.

What is going wrong?

Bonus question: `$this->quoteItem->save()` is deprecated - what to use instead?

*Update* I wrote a failing integration test for this:

```
public function testCanIncreaseNumberOfPages()
{
    $cart =  $this->cartBuilder->withProductRequest("proof", 1, $this->options)
        ->build();
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getFirstItem();

    /**
     * @var $itemInfo ItemInfo
     */
    $itemInfo = $this->itemInfoFactory->create(['quoteItem' => $quoteItem]);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $itemInfo->getNumberOfPages());

    $itemInfo->updateNumberOfPages(2);

    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $itemInfo = $this->itemInfoFactory->create(['quoteItem' => $quoteItem]);
    $this->assertEquals(2, $itemInfo->getNumberOfPages());
}
```

It fails the second assertion

```
Failed asserting that '1' matches expected 2.
```

*Upate3*

New update function:

```
public function updateNumberOfPages($pages)
{

    $qty = $pages * $this->getNumberOfCopies();

    $requestInfo = $this->orderOptions['info_buyRequest'];

    $requestInfo[self::OPTION_NAME_PAGES] = $pages;
    $requestInfo[self::OPTION_NAME_QTY] = $qty;

    $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestInfo);
    $this->cart->updateItem($this->quoteItem->getId(), $buyRequest);
    $this->cart->save();

    $this->quoteItem->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

    return $this;
}
```

New test:

```
public function testCanIncreaseNumberOfPages()
{
    $cart =  $this->cartBuilder->withProductRequest("proof", 1, $this->options)
        ->build();
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getFirstItem();

    $this->assertEquals(6.0, $quote->getGrandTotal());

    /**
     * @var $itemInfo ItemInfo
     */
    $itemInfo = $this->itemInfoFactory->create(['quoteItem' => $quoteItem]);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $itemInfo->getNumberOfPages());

    $itemInfo->updateNumberOfPages(2);

    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $itemInfo = $this->itemInfoFactory->create(['quoteItem' => $quoteItem]);
    $this->assertEquals(12.0, $quote->getGrandTotal());
    $this->assertEquals(2, $itemInfo->getNumberOfPages());
}
```

Fails in         $this->assertEquals(12.0, $quote->getGrandTotal());
 (expects 12, gets 6)

Comment: Did the quantity change in the DB? Also check if `getQuoteId()` is the same.

Comment: I am not even sure where to search it in the DB .. basically quote_item_option .. but we have buyRequests and options - maybe I have to update the buyRequest (or both)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/165201/81

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same that is done in `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdateItemOptions::execute` might be the way to got ...

This works in real-life but my integration test still needs fixing:

```
public function updateNumberOfPages($pages)
{
    $qty = $pages * $this->getNumberOfCopies();

    $requestInfo = $this->orderOptions['info_buyRequest'];
    $requestInfo[self::OPTION_NAME_PAGES][self::OPTION_ID_PROOF_FORMAT ] = $pages;
    $requestInfo[self::OPTION_NAME_QTY][self::OPTION_ID_PROOF_FORMAT] = $qty;

    $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestInfo);

    $item = $this->cart->updateItem($this->quoteItem->getId(), $buyRequest);

    if (is_string($item)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item));
    }
    if ($item->getHasError()) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item->getMessage()));
    }

    $this->cart->save();

    return $this;
}
```

*to be updated*