# Magento 1 OR 2 : Set custom product weight in quote

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, shipping, sales-quote, product-weight

I have a dynamic product which is based on user size input. On the basis of user size input I am calculating product price and weight.

I already set the product calculated price in custom price field of quote and set `additional_options` with all user input as custom option.

I also have to calculate the weight of the product based on user input and want to use it for shipping calculation.

I am trying to set product calculated weight in quote item as weight, but it get changed when quote refreshed or any extra activity on quote.

> How do I set product custom weight in quote and used it in shipping method ?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution to this? We have the same need.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 : use Plugin for Type : Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item

after method setProduct() which is a public method. setWeight('123') and return the results.

```
public function afterSetProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item, $results){


    $results->setWeight('80');

    return $results;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="sales_quote_save_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module_quote_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CartSetProduct"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Observer/CartSetProduct.php

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class CartSetProduct implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        // $cart = $observer->getCart();
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $item->getProduct()->setWeight(0.2);
            $item->setWeight(0.2);
            // $item->calcRowTotal();
        }
    }
}
?>
```